# Java ArrayList of Type Class behaves like it only has objects with reference to a global object

Tags: java, class, for-loop, arraylist, static

I need some help here - I want to do a little card game for learning reasons.
I have a class (Tree/Baum) and an ArrayList "TreeList" of several trees of object Tree.
Now I want to load different random objects of that class in a new ArraList called "PlayersHand".

To do this I have created a for-loop with a tmpObj of type Tree which loads a random index from ArrayList"TreeList" of all Trees. After that it modifies some values of the tmpObj by random (f.e. tree height). Then it adds this whole tmpObject to the ArrayList "PlayersHand".

The Problem is, that when I read out the values of the objects inside PlayersHand the modified values don't show the right way. They always show the last value of the treetype, so f.e. if the last tree of type ACER was 20m high, all the previous trees of type ACER are 20m high too.

It seems like all the objects in the ArrayList "playersHand" are just pointers to the different objects of ArrayList "TreeList".

But why ? And how can I fix it?

The code where the objects are copied:

```
//"PlayersHand get cards
    for(int i=0;i<amountOfCards;i++)
    {
        int randomNr = (int)(Math.random()* TreeList.size());
        Tree tmpTree = TreeList.get(randomNr);  
        tmpTree.modifyValues();
        playersHand.add(tmpTree);

        for(int y=0; y<playersHand.size();y++)
        {
                Tree tmpTree2 = playersHand.get(y);
        System.out.println(" - different values of that object shown here - ");     
        }
    }
```

Edit: Previously I had a more complex scenario. I tried to reduce complexity for better understanding.

Comment: You seem to be creating a lot of objects with lines like `tmpBaum = new Baum();`, then overwriting them immediately with `tmpBaum = Baumliste.get(zufallsKarte);`. Perhaps the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) might clear up the basics for you.

Comment: You also should avoid using any `static` variables.

Comment: So your concern is that a player should be able to hold, let's say, a 1st Acer tree of 10m height, and a 2nd Acer tree of 15m (and maybe even a 3rd Acer tree of some yet different height, etc.)?

Comment: I tried to avoid the static variables but I get errors then (most probably because the function I'm using them are in a different class file, because I don't want to have everything in a main file). @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes exactly, that's my concern. IMHO you can leave this line out " tmpBaum = new Baum();" , but I think the other tmpObjects are required. They are AFAIK temporarily and will be freed when the for loop has finished?!

Comment: I removed the static variables but the problem persists unfortunalely.

Comment: I also removed unneccessary lines- will edit in the main entr

Comment: There's a lot of detail and still a lot of details missing. Try to reduce the problem as much as possible: Reduce the issue to using just the `Baum` class and one other class with a simple `main` function ([a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You probably don't even need any loops and random invocations, just get a couple of objects and call `mittelWerteBerechnen` on them. Also post the code of that message and all variables it references, as it's very likely to be relevant.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for your answer! I updated the whole question , hope it is better understandable now.

Comment: I also tried a copy constructor in class Baum, but it doesn't work yet, although I think I'm on the right way

Answer (score 0):

I solved it - If someone has the same issue :
You have to use a copy constructor.